# Worksheets.Cells() giving "Application-Defined" error

Tags: vba, excel

I have some very simple code for setting cell A2 to the path/filename in an auto open macro.

```
Sub Auto_Open()
    Dim apath, aname, aref
    apath = Workbooks("Workbook.xlsm").Path
    aname = Workbooks("Workbook.xlsm").Name
    aref = apath & "\" & aname
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 1) = aref
End Sub
```

The last line fails on my machine, but works on a co-workers machine.  The problem is with the Cells object.  When I add a watch on the Cells object, it shows the "Application-Defined or object-defined error".  It's as if the Cells object doesn't exist.  What baffles me is that it works on my co-workers machine.

The workbook does have a couple of other protected worksheets, but Sheet1 is not protected.  I get the same issue when I un-protect the other sheets.

I've tried changing the Cells reference to a Range("A2") instead, same behaviour. However, if I set it to point to a different sheet, it works fine!

What is it about this sheet that's stopping me from accessing the Cells/Range property?

Comment: Possible that `aref` is causing some sort of error? Do you get the same error if you try to assign a simple string: `.Cells(2, 1) = "hello"`?  Also, try using explicitly the `.Value` property, although that may not help: `.Cells(2,1).Value = ...`

Comment: Are you *sure* there is a 'Sheet1' ? You could try: `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(2, 1) = aref`

Comment: @David-Zemens It's not a problem with aref, I can add a watch for the variable and it shows the expected value.  I tried ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(2,1) (it is the second sheet in the book), and I get the same issue.  If I add a watch on "ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2)", it shows the worksheet object as expected.

Comment: What *is* the expected value of `aref`? Even if the value is as-expected, the value may be causing an error. Try putting `Range("A1").Value = "= 5 minutes"` and you'll get a 1004 every time.  So, can you answer my other questions: if you assing a simple string like "hello" do you get the same error? Did you try explicitly using the `.Value` property also?

Comment: What's the difference between "Sheet1" and the different sheets you tried that worked?

Comment: @findwindow I guess that's wheat I need help discovering! There isn't anything different that I can tell.

Comment: You have the sheets before you so you're in best position to determine any differences XD